# How to lock a source table to block inserts during merge and backup?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

To perform a merge from a source table which gets updated continuously (ex: like every 1min) as well as copying the data from the source table to a backup table and then to delete the source table. Basically the data on which merge occurred should be backed up and cleaned up from source. The source table should be locked so that no changes (inserts,deletes etc) are made.

Assume the tables are called poc_a, poc_b, poc_c all with same structure [id,w,p,TimeStamp<-- 4 columns]
I want to do something like this:

```
begin tran merg
MERGE poc_c as Target
USING (
    
    select id,w,p,[TimeStamp] from (
     SELECT     id,w,p,[TimeStamp],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w, p 
       ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC) AS RN 
     FROM poc_a with (tablockx) 
                 ) DUPL_FILTER -- filter first row from N duplicate rows
    WHERE RN = 1 
     ) Source
ON
  Source.w = Target.w   AND   Source.p = Target.p 
  
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  update set
    Target.[id]       = Source.[id],
    Target.[w]       = Source.[w],
    Target.[p]            = Source.[p],
    Target.[TimeStamp]       = Source.[TimeStamp]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    insert ([id],[w],[p],[TimeStamp])   values(Source.id,Source.w,Source.p,Source.[TimeStamp])
  ;
  --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'

insert into poc_b select * from poc_a --will there be data loss here or below truncate?
truncate table poc_a

 commit tran merg
```

Comment: You probably might want to [rethink using Merge](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/08/what-to-avoid-if-you-want-to-use-merge/)

Comment: Also I recommend reading [So you want to use `MERGE`, eh?](//sqlblog.org/merge)

Comment: @Stu, ig merge attracts newbies and bugs. Considering that I already have the merge code, how should I do handle the insert and truncate part ?

Comment: @ThomA, will try not to use merge anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this line before begin transaction

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITED;`

Which will make merge read ONLY data that was commited before the merge transaction started, this will not lock the table for insterts, but the merge transaction will not acquire those changes before other transactions are commited.

If you want to completely lock access to a table that your transaction is using you could do

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`

Which is the highest level of isolation possible and will completely lock table for other transactions until your merge transaction is commited.

Comment: will the insert into and truncate have any issues ?

Comment: if you use `SERIALIZABLE` it will wait for your merge transaction to finish and insert only after that, if you use `READ COMMITED` it will insert immediately but merge transaction will only see data that was inserted/updated/deleted before it started